# Что означает -lstdc++ в C++?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

Есть такая строчка в cmd:

```
gcc test.cpp -o test555 -lstdc++
```

Что означает -lstdc++ и как расшифровывается?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

параметр `-l` говорит компоновщику подключить библиотеку.
В данном случае - `libstdc++`. Библиотеки указываются без префикса"lib"
Эту команду можно сократить, если использовать `g++`

```
g++ test.cpp -o test
```

`g++` подключает `libstdc++` автоматически